# Notepad++ // How do I remove everything between specific strings of text, including the strings themselves?

Tags: notepad++, regex

The following example is all in one line, and I have a ton of occurrences of this same type of thing that I want to fix. I'm looking to delete the repeated file paths. The first file path on each line is a single, but then every one after that is followed by `"><img src="RepeatOfThePath" class="_2yuc _3-96" />`

It's just the parts between `"><img src="` and `" class="_2yuc _3-96" />` that I'm looking to delete (including those strings), but without carrying out the command all the way to the end of the line, as that's where the date is (which should stay in place).

BEFORE:

```
User Two||User Two sent 8 photos. File locations: Messaging Archive/messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/49450603_219138382307432_3277446984746663936_n_219138378974099.jpgLnBrkMessaging Archive/messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/49764923_358739138271625_580785213139845120_n_358739134938292.jpg"><img src="messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/49764923_358739138271625_580785213139845120_n_358739134938292.jpg" class="_2yuc _3-96" />LnBrkMessaging Archive/messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/48404864_921427388047408_7300876900581244928_n_921427381380742.jpg"><img src="messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/48404864_921427388047408_7300876900581244928_n_921427381380742.jpg" class="_2yuc _3-96" />LnBrkMessaging Archive/messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/49164579_214366476179977_4468743459502555136_n_214366469513311.jpg"><img src="messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/49164579_214366476179977_4468743459502555136_n_214366469513311.jpg" class="_2yuc _3-96" />LnBrkMessaging Archive/messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/49787371_2255721791336152_3381788336120135680_n_2255721784669486.jpg"><img src="messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/49787371_2255721791336152_3381788336120135680_n_2255721784669486.jpg" class="_2yuc _3-96" />LnBrkMessaging Archive/messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/48985330_811888555823956_4821470710998237184_n_811888549157290.jpg"><img src="messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/48985330_811888555823956_4821470710998237184_n_811888549157290.jpg" class="_2yuc _3-96" />LnBrkMessaging Archive/messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/49658202_599404630515667_5325374562135703552_n_599404627182334.jpg"><img src="messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/49658202_599404630515667_5325374562135703552_n_599404627182334.jpg" class="_2yuc _3-96" />LnBrkMessaging Archive/messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/49021071_212456299699526_956147449091588096_n_212456293032860.jpg"><img src="messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/49021071_212456299699526_956147449091588096_n_212456293032860.jpg" class="_2yuc _3-96" />||Dec 30, 2018, 10:29 AM
```

AFTER:

```
User Two||User Two sent 8 photos. File locations: Messaging Archive/messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/49450603_219138382307432_3277446984746663936_n_219138378974099.jpgLnBrkMessaging Archive/messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/49764923_358739138271625_580785213139845120_n_358739134938292.jpgLnBrkMessaging Archive/messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/48404864_921427388047408_7300876900581244928_n_921427381380742.jpgLnBrkMessaging Archive/messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/49164579_214366476179977_4468743459502555136_n_214366469513311.jpgLnBrkMessaging Archive/messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/49787371_2255721791336152_3381788336120135680_n_2255721784669486.jpgLnBrkMessaging Archive/messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/48985330_811888555823956_4821470710998237184_n_811888549157290.jpgLnBrkMessaging Archive/messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/49658202_599404630515667_5325374562135703552_n_599404627182334.jpgLnBrkMessaging Archive/messages/inbox/UserOne_iW_GxLYs3A/photos/49021071_212456299699526_956147449091588096_n_212456293032860.jpg||Dec 30, 2018, 10:29 AM
```

What should I do?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do. Could you edit your question to include an example of 'before' and 'after' blocks of text?

Comment: I added a before/after sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `"><img\h+.+?class="_2yuc _3-96" />`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
"><img                  # literally
\h+                     # 1 or more horizontal spaces
.+?                     # 1 or more any character but newline
class="_2yuc _3-96" />  # literally
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]